# Force YAML to format string as a quoted string

Tags: python, yaml

I have the following string `"058"` that I need to dump into YAML, but when I do a dump, it gets converted into a "number". (no quotes). All other number-like strings seem to work fine.

```
yaml.dump({'a': '058'})
```

returns:

```
'a: 058\n'
```

as you will notice, the string doesn't have the quote around it. Compare to another number:

```
yaml.dump({'a': '057'})
```

returns:

```
"a: '057'\n"
```

and that one has the single quotes around the string. Every other number I have tested does the quotes except for '058'.

How do I force YAML to have the quotes around it?

Comment: I can guess why it happens, but not what to do about it.  058 is not a valid number in Python, but 057 is (octal constant).

Comment: Your theory seems to be correct. Any number with an 8 or 9 in it has the same behavior, and numbers without get the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain regular expressions defined in yaml library. Of course their purpose is to parse popular formats (i.a octal numbers). The exact regexp that causes this behaviour is

```
[-+]?0[0-7_]+
```

To handle this problem you need to add custom explicit resolver, but keep in mind that oct values containing numbers from beyond the scope of 0-8 will be parsed improperly - that is like they were proper oct values.

And here's the solution:

```
import re
from yaml import dump
from yaml.resolver import Resolver

Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    re.compile(r'''^([-+]?0[0-9_]+)$''', re.X),
    list('-+0123456789'))

yaml.dump({'a': '058'})
```

Then you'll get

```
"a: '058'\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a string. Quotes arent required in YAML; the value doesn't indicate an octal number

```py
import yaml
from yaml import CLoader as Loader

yaml.load('a: 058\n', Loader=Loader)
#  {'a': '058'}
type(yaml.load('a: 058\n', Loader=Loader)['a'])
# str
```

Comment: I have an issue where the quotes actually matter in another program. So while python reads this as a string, is there a way to force the quotes?

Comment: You could try playing with the `encoding` parameter of the dump method. Or defining your own Dumper class